# How to get value from javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

Here is my code. I want to return value of `front_image` but its returning blank string.

```
function get_front_image(callbackFunction){
    var front_image="";
    html2canvas($('#selector'), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
             front_image=canvas.toDataURL();
             callbackFunction(front_image);
        }
    });
}
```

i m trying to get it value of `front_image` like this

```
var f;
    var a=get_front_image(function(value){
      f= value;
     });
    alert(f);// it returns blank
```

how can i get this value from this function please suggest me the answer.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function `get_front_image` you assign an empty string to the variable `front_image`, then you call the `html2canvas` function, which has an `onrendered` function. This function is called [asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559032/easy-to-understand-definition-of-asynchronous-event), so by the time you're returning the `front_image` variable, the `onrendered` function is not called yet, which means `front_image` is still an empty string.

Mostly when doing asynchronous stuff, you'll work with callback functions. Here that could look something like this:

```
function get_front_image(callbackFunction){
    var front_image="";
    html2canvas($('#selector'), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
             front_image=canvas.toDataURL();
             callbackFunction(front_image);
        }
    });
}

var f;
get_front_image(function(value){
    f = value;
    alert(f); //will return your value
});
alert(f); //Wont alert your value
```

To make it clear in which order what's executed:

1. Var f is declared `var f;`
2. `get_fron_image` is called, and the html2canvas function is called. This is **asynchronous**, so the `onrendered` function will be called just when it's finished, and we can't know when this will happen.
3. The `alert(f); //wont alert your value` line is executed. As the `onrendered` function hasn't been called yet, `f` does not have a value yet.
4. Eventually, the `onrendered` function is executed, and the `callbackFunction` is called, where `alert(f);` shows your value as expected. Whatever you want to do with your variable `f` must happen in the callbackFunction in order to work.

Comment: var f;
`get_front_image(function(value){
    f = value;
    alert(f);// it alerts here 
});

alert (f);// but not here :(
`

Comment: it doesn't alert out of the function

Comment: yes, because it's asynchronous. Check out the link I provided in my answer. If you're still having trouble, edit your answer and specify what you're trying to achieve, and where the variable f will be needed.

Comment: I have edited the answer please check it once and suggest me the solution.

Comment: You won't get the value there, ever. Not possible. As I said you need to show us for what you need the variable `f`, otherwise an answer other than what I've given you is not possible

Comment: thanks for your answer. is it possible to get value of f using settimelimit() ?

Comment: If you mean `setTimeout`, then yes. But do **NOT** do that. It's very bad practice, and there's always a risk that the onrendered function won't be finished, even if you use a `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

html2canvas onrendered will run asynchronously, by then your function returning the empty var which was not initialized.

So, we have to use callback functions for long running tasks. You can implement your functions as below.

```
function get_front_image(callback){
 html2canvas($('#selector'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var url = canvas.toDataURL();
      callback(url);
    }
});
}
```

And call the function as below.

```
get_front_image(function(link){
alert(link);
});
```

Comment: why is this here ` var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
`

Comment: I need `var link= get_front_image(function(link){

}); alert(link)`

Comment: As get_front_image(...) function is asynchronous, It will **not possible** to get value out side callback. We don't know the function execution time at all.