# Callback after $.get?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask

I have a javascript function foo. I want bar to be called when foo is complete. I have tried it as a callback. It does not work. Bar is called while foo is still executing the $.get (which starts a very long python routine on the server).

```
  function foo(callback){
    $.get(
        url="/myurl",
        data={key:($(this).attr('data-button'))}, 
        function(returndata) {
            var array = eval(returndata);
            drawTable(array);
      });

      callback();
  }
```

foo(bar);

This however works. I am confused as to why...

```
  function foo(callback){
    $.get(
        url="/myurl",
        data={key:($(this).attr('data-button'))}, 
        function(returndata) {
            var array = eval(returndata);
            drawTable(array);
            callback();
      });

  }
```

foo(bar);

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Comment: Callback happens when the call is returned:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4560233/14104 The first one you treat it like it is a synchronous call, second one is treated correctly for an asynchronous call.

Comment: So, in the first example, I call $.get, which starts running, and then because it was called bar is called (even through $.get is not complete)... in the second example, $.get has a callback to  bar when it is done, so it works. Do I understand that correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because  [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) is asynchronous. 
from the docs ...

```
This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

you can think of it being run in a separate thread. so bar() wont act as a callback . but in your 2nd example  "function(returndata)" is the callback function for $.get hence giving bar() inside will do the job as now bar() will only be called after $.get is finished.

Comment: Thanks, That makes sense with my comment on the question

Answer (score 0):

it's working in second case as 'bar()' is being called once the response comes .Now coming back to callback, Simple concept of writing callback is below :

```js
function func1(callback) {
  alert('func1');
  callback();
}

function func2() {
  alert('func2');
}

func1(func2);
```

so in your case, ideally this should work :

```js
 function foo(callback) {
   $.get(
     url = "/myurl",
     data = {
       key: ($(this).attr('data-button'))
     },
     function(returndata) {
       var array = eval(returndata);
       drawTable(array);
       callback.call();
     });
 }

 function bar() {
   //todo

 }

 foo(bar);
```