# Access to variable interval

Tags: javascript, angularjs, global-variables

How can i get qLength in this :

```
var intervalPromise = $interval( function (){
    $http.get(request).success(function (datatemp) {                    // Get Queue info JSON every 2s
        if (angular.equals(store.queues, datatemp)) {               //if like the last, no change
            console.log('Same values');
            qLength =  store.queues.Jobs.length;
        } else {                                                    //Else, update
            store.queues = datatemp;
            console.log('Values updated')
        }
    });
}, 3000, 0);

console.log(qLength);
```

console.log(qLength) return undefined.

When i try using window, it's same result.

Comment: Where is the line from your code? `console.log(qlength)`

Comment: use `$scope.qLength`

Comment: @RameshRajendran Outside of the bloc. I edited to show you.

Comment: @K.Toress I get undefined too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get `qLength` in this manner because the `$interval()` and the `$http.get()` request are running in an asynchronous manner. You're trying to access a value that can only be accessed asynchronously in a synchronous manner. A simple way to get the value you're looking for is to create a function that accepts the length itself and have it invoked when the request has been fulfilled.

```
var qLengthCheck = function(length) {
  // This logs the length in each interval
  console.log(length);
};

var intervalPromise = $interval( function (){
    $http.get(request).success(function (datatemp) {                    // Get Queue info JSON every 2s
        if (angular.equals(store.queues, datatemp)) {               //if like the last, no change
            console.log('Same values');
            qLength =  store.queues.Jobs.length;
        } else {                                                    //Else, update
            store.queues = datatemp;
            console.log('Values updated')
        }

        qLengthCheck(length);
    });
}, 3000, 0);
```

If you're having trouble about asynchronous processes, you can check this good non-programming example in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559032/easy-to-understand-definition-of-asynchronous-event#answer-4560233)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and solution. If i understand well, i need to use my length variable when it has been defined but not before, neither outside bloc (or i should use your solution).

Answer (score 0):

you have missed assign variable for `qLength`

try this below code

```
**var qLength="";**
var intervalPromise = $interval( function (){
    $http.get(request).success(function (datatemp) {                    // Get Queue info JSON every 2s
        if (angular.equals(store.queues, datatemp)) {               //if like the last, no change
            console.log('Same values');
            qLength =  store.queues.Jobs.length;
        } else {                                                    //Else, update
            store.queues = datatemp;
            console.log('Values updated')
        }
    });
}, 3000, 0);

console.log(qLength);
```

Comment: As ryeballar said above, it was a synchron/ asynchron matter.