# Parsing GeoJSON with leaflet from an external API

Tags: javascript, json, api, leaflet, geojson

I'm trying to use an external API to retrieve GeoJSON data and ultimately show the data on a map. I'm using the leaflet library for the map and the issue I'm facing is that the data I get from this API seems fine (i.e. if I take the data from the console.log and then use it directly in the "L.geoJson(**WHAT TO INPUT HERE**)" it works) but for some reason if I try to use the object itselft it doesn't work.

```
                var map = L.map('map').setView([48.85, 2.35], 13);
                var stamenLayer = L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                  attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a>. Data by <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>, under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0">CC BY SA</a>.'
                }).addTo(map);

                function reqListener () {
                  console.log(this.response);
                }

                var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
                oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
                oReq.open("GET", "http://dataratp.opendatasoft.com/api/records/1.0/download?dataset=liste-des-commerces-de-proximite-agrees-ratp&rows=100&format=geojson");
                oReq.send();
                L.geoJson(**WHAT TO INPUT HERE**).addTo(map);
```

Not too sure what's causing the issue as the data looks fine (I tested it on http://geojsonlint.com/).

Thanks for your help,
Julien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of data you're receiving is a string. `L.GeoJSON` expects a GeoJSON object. You can convert the string to an object using the `JSON.parse` method:

> The JSON.parse() method parses a string as JSON.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

```
L.geoJson(JSON.parse(this.response)).addTo(map);
```

Next you'll need to know that XMLhttpRequest is asynchronous. See: [Easy to understand definition of "asynchronous event"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559032) Which in short means that when `L.GeoJSON` is being called, `oReq.send` might not be ready yet. That's where the eventlistener comes in. It calls the `reqListener` method when `oReq.send` is done receiving. You need to create your `L.GeoJSON` layer in the `reqListener` method like so:

```
function reqListener () {
    L.geoJson(JSON.parse(this.response)).addTo(map);
}
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/ODe622?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot it works!! For a first question on stackoverflow I'm more than happy with the detailed answer and the reactivity!