# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined when calling a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's wrong with my script, I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function connected() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.ajax({
        type:"get",
        url:"cgi-bin/check",
        success:function(data) {
            if (data.indexOf("192.168.1.1:1080")>-1) {
                var audio = new Audio("on.ogg");
                audio.play();
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Connected";
                clearTimeout(loop);
            }
        }
    });
    loop = setTimeout(connected, 1000);
}
function disconnected() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.ajax({
        type:"get",
        url:"cgi-bin/check",
        success:function(data) {
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "function disconnected ";
            if (data.indexOf("ssh disconnected")>-1) {
                var audio = new Audio("off.ogg");
                audio.play();
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Disconnected: "+data;
                clearTimeout(loop);
            }
        }
    });
    loop = setTimeout(disconnected, 1000);
}
function notif() {
    var loop;
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.ajax({
        type:"get",
        url:"cgi-bin/check",
        success:function(data) {
            if (data.indexOf("192.168.1.1:1080")>-1) {
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "It's connected, waiting to disconnect";
                disconnected().then(connected);
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "It's disconnected, waiting to connect";
                connected().then(disconnected);
            }
        }
    });
}
notif();
</script>
<p id="output"></p>
```

That is the script to notify me whether my ssh tunnel gets disconnected / connected. It'll play a sound on each occurence.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, your `disconnected` and `connected` functions do not return anything, and you are trying to do `.then()` to an `undefined` value.

`.then()` is a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) method

By the look of your code it seems that you do not fully understand how asynchronous things work, so I would suggest you read a few resources on that.

**https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests**

**[Easy to understand definition of "asynchronous event"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559032/easy-to-understand-definition-of-asynchronous-event)**

**http://rowanmanning.com/posts/javascript-for-beginners-async/**

Answer (score 0):

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and
>   jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare
>   your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(),
>   and jqXHR.always() instead.

Change your code to look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type:"get",
        url:"cgi-bin/check"}).done(function(data) {} );
```

You may use **done** or **then**.  **then** will catch errors as well as success responses.

Comment: I did what you suggested but I got an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) test.php:16` this is my modified script http://pastebin.com/Gk5Zpq5T

Comment: I apologize for the syntax error - it has been corrected.  The point of my answer was that you shouldn't be using **success**, you need to use **done** or **then**.