# Cannot get $_SESSION variable correctly from angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, session

I'm using angularjs, now I want get a php session variable, so I've create a php file called session.php and inside have this content:

```
$_SESSION['phone'] = '55551864';
return json_encode($_SESSION['phone']);
```

from angularj, I've this request:

```
$http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'session.php'
}).then(function successCallback(response) 
{
    var phone_number = JSON.stringify(response);
    alert(phone_number);
}, function errorCallback(response) {
  alert("error happean!");
});
```

the alert display this content:

```
{"data":"","status":200,"config":{"method":"GET","transormRequest":[null],"transoformResponse":[null],"url":"session.php","headers":{}},"statusText":"OK"}
```

I just want return 55551864 what happean?

Comment: In your php you need to do `echo` not `return` ->  `echo json_encode($_SESSION['phone']);`. I am not familiar with angularjs, but my guess is after fixing the php issue with `echo`, then your number will be in the `data`, so you could do `response.data` -> `var phone_number = JSON.stringify(response.data);`

Comment: ok now I get this: "\"555518641\""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) `response` object has these properties

> - **data** – `{string|Object}` – The
>     response body transformed with the transform functions.
> - **status** – `{number}` – HTTP
>     status code of the response.
> - **headers** –
>     `{function([headerName])}` – Header getter function.
> - **config** – `{Object}` – The
>     configuration object that was used to generate the request.
> - **statusText** – `{string}` – HTTP status text of the response.

So what you are looking for is `response.data`. As pointed out in the comments you should use echo instead of return. It does not make sense to JSON encode a single string, just echo out the string. Then there is no need to decode it on the client.

```
$_SESSION['phone'] = '55551864';
echo $_SESSION['phone'];
...
var phone_number = response.data;
```

Comment: Okay now working, but I have a question: why I get $http content after the page load?

Comment: `$http` is an asynchronous request to the server, meaning the code after it will continue to execute while the web request is being sent and received. See [Easy to understand definition of “asynchronous event”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559032/easy-to-understand-definition-of-asynchronous-event)

Comment: oh yes, I'll try to wait the result