# How to make sure data has been loaded through AJAX before rendering a ReactJS component?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I have a parent component named `UsersTable`(it's a child of some other component and has `users` and `roles`as its props). The `getRoles()` function is getting all the roles for a user using an ajax request. The result is returned to `render()` and stores in `allroles`variable. The problem is since Ajax is asynchronous, I'm not always getting the values I need in `allroles` variable. It is sometimes empty or returns the same value for all users. I guess I should somehow use componentDidMount and componentWillReceiveProps according to descriptions. But I couldn't figure it out. Also, I think `allroles` should be a state but doing that put the code in an infinite loop, and the browser keeps calling the ajax request forever!

Here is the parent component code:

```
export const UsersTable = React.createClass({
    getRoles(){
        var oneRole = "";
        this.props.users.forEach(function(user){
            server.getUserRoles(user.id,          
                (results) => {
                    this.oneRole =results['hits']['hits']
                    notifications.success("Get was successful ");
                },
                () => {
                    notifications.danger("get failed ");
                });  
            }.bind(this));
        return this.oneRole;
    },

    render() {
        var rows = [];
        var allroles = this.getRoles()
        this.props.users.map(function(user) {
            rows.push( <UserRow userID={user.id} 
                                userEmail={user.email} 
                                userRoles={allroles} 
                                roles={this.props.roles} />); 
            }.bind(this)); 
        return (
            <table className="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Email Address</th>
                        <th>Role</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }    
});
```

And here is the child component code:

```
export const UserRow = React.createClass({
    var showRoles = this.props.userRoles.map((role) => <div> {role.description || ''}</div>);
    render(){
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.userEmail}</td>
                <td>{showRoles}</td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: you dont use well the ajax asyncronous concept. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559032/easy-to-understand-definition-of-asynchronous-event

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in saying you should use the life cycle methods.

As a general rule, use `componentDidMount` if you just need to populate the data once at the beginning.

Use `componentWillReceiveProps` if it has to collect more data (based on props changing).

As a sidenote, for your particular example, you seem to be calling the backend multiple times via a loop. Its impossible to tell from the question, but if you are using a promise library you can push all those promises into an array, and do a `Promise.all().then(/* update state */)`

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it. for example assume I have a componentDidMount function, in its body I should call getRoles(), right? But then how to pass the user to it ? Also,  I don't know about Promises :( Is there any other way to fix it? Should I better move it from render() function to a new function? I think I've read somewhere that states shouldn't get update in render(). Maybe that's the reason....

Comment: i'll put togther a quick codepen. what request library are you using? axios?

Answer (score 0):

First things first, to put that in a state without making it an infinite loop, you need a constructor method in which you call the super() method and then you are able to define the state. So you need something like this:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
       allroles: null
    }
}
```

After that, as you correctly pointed out, you need the life cycle hook: [`componentDidMount()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount),

You need the first one to populate your state. So to call it, should look something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.setState({allroles: this.getRoles()})
}
```

Now if you need to fetch new updates, you must know whether this updates will be triggered as a user's interaction consequence (e.g. they add a new entry on the table) or time-based update (e.g. using a interval that calls `this.getRole()` every certain amount of time). Either way, you would need to use `this.setState({allroles: this.getRoles()})` again.

In this case, you don't need `componentWillReceiveProps()` because this component is managing its own state without receiving props. If you would have received the roles as props, you would have need `componentWillReceiveProps()`

And last, to answer why you had an infinite loop is because `this.setState()` triggers a re-rendering of the component. That means that if you call `this.setState()` in the `render()` method, you will

1. render()
2. re-render triggered
3. render()
4. re-render triggered
   ...

That's why you can't call directly `this.setState()` in your `render()` method and rather call it either on a event or on certain lifecycle hooks (the ones that are called BEFORE the rendering happens or are considered to be the INITIAL render)