# Why is array.length equal to 0 when it's not empty, and how can I loop through it?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, loops, state

I'm bit in confusion, this should be pretty obvious but I'm getting lost trying to figure everything out.

I'm creating a form with React, and the user can select a few images. My initial goal is to display the preview, but for a reason I can't understand, I can't map the array of results even though I can see with a `console.log()` that it's not empty

Here is how I create the array:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        // Some other elements
        m_filename: [],
    };
}

handleMultiUpload() {

    let files = document.getElementById('multiple_files_upload');
    let files_result = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < files.files.length; i++) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(files.files[i]);
        reader.onloadend = function() {
            // console.log(reader.result);
            files_result.push({
                "id": i,
                "name": files.files[i].name,
                "img": reader.result
            });
        }
    }

    this.setState({
        m_file: files_result,
    });
}

render() {

    const { m_file } = this.state;

    // rest of my code
}
```

From there, when I `console.log` the `m_file` variable, it returns something looking like this:

```
[
  0:
    id: 0
    name: "file.jpg"
    img: "[base64 file rendered here]"
  1:
    id: 1
    name: "cat.jpg"
    img: "[base64 file rendered here]"
  ...etc
]
```

I'm trying to loop through `m_file` by doing the following:

```
{
  m_file !== null && m_file.map(function(tile) {
      return (
          <li key={tile.id}>
              <img src={tile.img}/>
          </li>
      )
}
```

The problems are multiples:

- `m_file.length` returns 0
- As a consequence I can't manage to loop through it and display my images
- Even though the console.log() make them show as an array, when I `console.log(typeof m_file)`, it returns object. I guess because it's a `state` object, but... how can I deal with it, while I have no problem mapping through json elsewhere?

I have the feeling I'm ignoring something obvious.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `FileReader` is async operation, so when you setState, `file_result` is empty.
Try to `setState` inside the `reader.onloadend` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MDN:

> The FileReader object lets web applications **asynchronously** read the
>   contents of files (or raw data buffers) stored on the user's computer,
>   using File or Blob objects to specify the file or data to read.

Since dealing with `FileReader` is asynchronous, when you `setState`, your variable `file_result` is still empty array.

One of possible solution, is call `setState` inside `reader.onloadend` function, just after pushing items to the array

```
let self = this;
reader.onloadend = function() {
   // console.log(reader.result);
   files_result.push({
      "id": i,
      "name": files.files[i].name,
      "img": reader.result
   });
   self.setState({
       m_file: files_result,
   });   
}
```

Note: `this` keyword would be binded to `FileReader` Object, so correct reference shall be kept in variable.

Here is the nice explanation of Async stuff in Javascript - https://stackoverflow.com/a/4560233/3918577